# How can I create a new record of data and save it to the SQL database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am working on a project in MVC but also incorporating a ViewModel Layer. I am using two different data tables. The first one is called Users. That has a lot of different properties. The second one is called UserProfile. That only has the Username email and password in it. The tables are linked in the database by the UserNumber field.

I have a view that allows a user to be created and information about the Store Definition, StoreOwnerDefinition, Store Region Definition and Store Type Definition that will be selected using the drop downs. How can I get the information selected from the drop downs in the view into the SQL database.

Here is what I have in the Controller:

````
       public ActionResult UserCreateNew()
            {


              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              // Open UserStoreDefinition table and create a List.
              dt = new DataTable();
              string constr =
             string strSQL = 

              using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess(constr))
              {
                dt = da.GetDataTable(strSQL, CommandType.Text);
              }

              // Convert a DataTable to a list. 
              m.lstStoreDefinition = LinqExtensions.ToListof<UserStoreDefinition>(dt);

              dt = new DataTable();
              //strSQL = "StoreOwnerDefinitions";
              strSQL = "SELECT distinct StoreOwnerName, StoreOwnerNumber FROM UserStoreDefinition"
                + " WHERE (UserStoreDefinition.UserNumber = " + m.UserNumber + ")"
                + " AND (UserStoreDefinition.StoreOwnerNumber <> -1)";

              using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess(constr))
              {
                dt = da.GetDataTable(strSQL, CommandType.Text);
              }
              m.lstStoreOwnerDefinitions = LinqExtensions.ToListof<UserStoreDefinition>(dt);

              dt = new DataTable();
              //strSQL = "StoreRegionDefinitions";


              using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess(constr))
              {
                dt = da.GetDataTable(strSQL, CommandType.Text);
              }
              m.lstStoreRegionDefinitions = LinqExtensions.ToListof<UserStoreDefinition>(dt);

              dt = new DataTable();
              //strSQL = "StoreTypeDefinitions";
              strSQL = "SELECT distinct StoreTypeName, StoreTypeNumber FROM UserStoreDefinition"
              + " WHERE (UserStoreDefinition.UserNumber = " + m.UserNumber + ")"
              + " AND (UserStoreDefinition.StoreTypeNumber <> -1)";

              using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess(constr))
              {
                dt = da.GetDataTable(strSQL, CommandType.Text);
              }
              m.lstStoreTypeDefinitions = LinqExtensions.ToListof<UserStoreDefinition>(dt);

              # endregion

              return View(m);
            }

    ```

    In my View Model I have: 

    ```

    and in the View I have: 

    ```





    <div class="spacerBody">
        <h2 class="admin-home-link orange-titles orange-titles-large">@Html.ActionLink("Create Users", "AdminIndex")</h2>

        <div class="to-link navlinks"> @Html.ActionLink("Users", "UserList") | @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Role", "RoleManageUser")</div>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration Form</legend>
                <ol class="comtrexBlue-text">
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <button class="btn larger" type="submit">Create</button>
            </fieldset>

        }


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              @Html.DropDownList
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              @Html.DropDownList
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              @Html.DropDownList
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              @Html.DropDownList       </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
````

I guess my first step would getting the dropdown info from the View. Right not its not executing the stored procedure and passing in the parameters.

Comment: You really need to parametrise your statements. What you have right now is just a big injection issue. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Larnu I have added some stuff that I left out. I will take a look at the article but do you have further suggestions?

Comment: You should pass a controller and action to Html.BeginForm() so that you can post the form data back to your contoller -> Html.BeginForm("UserCreateNew", "CONTROLLERNAMEHERE")

Answer (score 1):

You need to post your form back to the controller, and pass the form data:

1) Set the Action, Controller and Method in BeginForm

```
@Html.BeginForm("UserCreateNew", "CONTROLLERNAMEHERE", FormMethod.Post)
```

2) Modify the UserCreateNew action to take in the form data as UserCreateNewViewModel

```
public ActionResult UserCreateNew(UserCreateNewViewModel userData)
        {
```

userData should then have all the data entered in your form.